# Breaking Up CSV By Regex in Python

Tags: python, regex, csv, pandas

I have a file formatted as below:

```
S1A23
0.01,0.01
0.02,0.02
0.03,0.03
S25A123
0.05,0.06
0.07,0.08
S3034A1
1000,0.04
2000,0.08
3000,0.1
```

I'd like to break it up by each "S_*A*_", and compute the correlation coefficient of the data below. So far, I have:

```
import re
import pandas as pd

test = pd.read_csv("predict.csv",sep=('S\d+A\d+'))

print test
```

but that only gives me:

```
  Unnamed: 0     ,
0  0.01,0.01  None
1  0.02,0.02  None
2  0.03,0.03  None
3        NaN     ,
4  0.05,0.06  None
5  0.07,0.08  None
6        NaN     ,
7  1000,0.04  None
8  2000,0.08  None
9   3000,0.1  None

[10 rows x 2 columns]
```

I'd, ideally, like to keep the regex delimiter, and have something like:

```
S1A23: 1.0
S2A123: 0.86
S303A1: 0.75
```

Is this possible?

**EDIT**
When running large files (~250k lines), I receive the following error. It is not a problem with the data, as when I break the ~250k lines into smaller chunks, all pieces run fine.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/adamg/PycharmProjects/Subj_AnswerCorrCoef/GetCorrCoef.py", line 15, in <module>
    print(result)
  File "/Users/adamg/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/base.py", line 35, in __str__
    return self.__bytes__()
  File "/Users/adamg/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/base.py", line 47, in __bytes__
    return self.__unicode__().encode(encoding, 'replace')
  File "/Users/adamg/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/series.py", line 857, in __unicode__
    result = self._tidy_repr(min(30, max_rows - 4))
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'NoneType' and 'int'
```

My exact code is:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import csv
pd.options.display.max_rows = None
fileName = 'keyStrokeFourgram/TESTING1'

df = pd.read_csv(fileName, names=['pause', 'probability'])
mask = df['pause'].str.match('^S\d+_A\d+')
df['S/A'] = (df['pause']
              .where(mask, np.nan)
              .fillna(method='ffill'))
df = df.loc[~mask]

result = df.groupby(['S/A']).apply(lambda grp: grp['pause'].corr(grp['probability']))
print(result)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `sep` parameter is used for specifying the pattern which separates values on the same line. It can not be used for separating rows of the csv into separate dataframes.

Edit: There is a way to read the csv into a DataFrame using `read_csv`. This is preferable to using a Python loop (as done in my original answer) since [`read_csv` should be faster](http://wesmckinney.com/blog/?p=543). This could be important -- particularly for large csv files.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv("data", names=['x', 'y'])
mask = df['x'].str.match('^S\d+A\d+')         # 1
df['type'] = (df['x']
              .where(mask, np.nan)            # 2
              .fillna(method='ffill'))        # 3
df = df.loc[~mask]                            # 4

result = df.groupby(['type']).apply(lambda grp: grp['x'].corr(grp['y']))
print(result)
```

yields

```
type
S1A23      1.000000
S25A123    1.000000
S3034A1    0.981981
dtype: float64
```

---

1. The mask is True on the rows that have a "type" in the `'x'` column.

   ```
   In [139]: mask
   Out[139]: 
   0      True
   1     False
   2     False
   3     False
   4      True
   5     False
   6     False
   7      True
   8     False
   9     False
   10    False
   Name: x, dtype: bool
   ```
2. `df['x'].where(mask, np.nan)` returns a Series, equal to `df['x']` where
   the mask is True, and np.nan otherwise.
3. Forward-fill in the nans with the currency values

   ```
   In [141]: df['x'].where(mask, np.nan).fillna(method='ffill')
   Out[141]: 
   0       S1A23
   1       S1A23
   2       S1A23
   3       S1A23
   4     S25A123
   5     S25A123
   6     S25A123
   7     S3034A1
   8     S3034A1
   9     S3034A1
   10    S3034A1
   Name: x, dtype: object
   ```
4. Select only those rows where the mask is False

---

Original answer:

Unfortunately, I don't see a way to read your data file directly into an appropriate DataFrame. You'll need to do some massaging of the rows to get it into the right form, using a Python loop.

```
import pandas as pd
import csv

def to_columns(f):
    val = None
    for row in csv.reader(f):
        if len(row) == 1:
            val = row[0]
        else:
            yield [val] + row

with open('data') as f:
    df = pd.DataFrame.from_records(to_columns(f), columns=['type', 'x', 'y'])

print(df)
result = df.groupby(['type']).apply(lambda grp: grp['x'].corr(grp['y']))
print(result)
```

Comment: Thanks for the update. I do have a large amount of data, though, and it's not printing out all of the data. I've tried it in PyCharm and the Terminal, but in both cases it only prints a couple dozen datapoints, with a "..." in the middle. Any idea how to get all of the data?

Comment: Put `pd.options.display.max_rows = None` in your script to see all the rows. Type `help(pd.set_option)` to see the available options. Another alternative to print all the rows is to use `print(df.to_string())`.

Comment: Two followup questions about this, if you don't mind: 1) How can I change it to use Spearman instead of Pearson correlation? 2) I'm getting an error when I try to feed in a lot of chunks (~5k). I can copy the error if you'd like.

Comment: 1) Change `corr(grp['y'])` to `corr(grp['y'], method='spearman')`. 2) Please post the full traceback error message, and the code you are running too.

Comment: I added a suggestion for how to fix the error [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/22824104/190597).

Comment: Arrr, you just wanted me bounty, eh, mate? Well, yer earned it! Arrrr!