# Python Pandas: Increase Maximum Number of Rows

Tags: python, numpy, pandas

I am processing a large text file (500k lines), formatted as below:

```
S1_A16
0.141,0.009340221649748676
0.141,4.192618196894668E-5
0.11,0.014122135626540204
S1_A17
0.188,2.3292323316081486E-6
0.469,0.007928706856794138
0.172,3.726771730573038E-5
```

I'm using the code below to return the correlation coefficients of each series, e.g. S!_A16:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import csv
pd.options.display.max_rows = None
fileName = 'wordUnigramPauseTEST.data'

df = pd.read_csv(fileName, names=['pause', 'probability'])
mask = df['pause'].str.match('^S\d+_A\d+')
df['S/A'] = (df['pause']
              .where(mask, np.nan)
              .fillna(method='ffill'))
df = df.loc[~mask]

result = df.groupby(['S/A']).apply(lambda grp: grp['pause'].corr(grp['probability']))
print(result)
```

However, on some large files, this returns the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/adamg/PycharmProjects/Subj_AnswerCorrCoef/GetCorrCoef.py", line 15, in <module>
    print(result)
  File "/Users/adamg/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/base.py", line 35, in __str__
    return self.__bytes__()
  File "/Users/adamg/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/base.py", line 47, in __bytes__
    return self.__unicode__().encode(encoding, 'replace')
  File "/Users/adamg/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/series.py", line 857, in __unicode__
    result = self._tidy_repr(min(30, max_rows - 4))
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'NoneType' and 'int'
```

I understand that this is related to the `print` statement, but how do I fix it?

**EDIT**: 
This is related to the maximum number of rows. Does anyone know how to accommodate a greater number of rows?

Comment: A useful trick here (if you're using ipython) is to %debug and find out where the problem is. Tricky to say without a reproducible example.

Comment: My guess would be bad data, try checking the data for type...

Comment: Nothing to do with the data. As I said in the Edit, it has to do with the maximum number of rows.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The error message:

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'NoneType' and 'int'
```

is saying `None` minus an `int` is a TypeError. If you look at the next-to-last line in the traceback you see that the only subtraction going on there is

```
max_rows - 4
```

So `max_rows` must be `None`. If you dive into `/Users/adamg/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/series.py`, near line 857 and ask yourself how `max_rows` could end up being equal to `None`, you'll see that somehow

```
get_option("display.max_rows")
```

must be returning `None`.

This part of the code is calling `_tidy_repr` which is used to summarize the Series. `None` is the correct value to set when you want pandas to display *all* lines of the `Series`.
So this part of the code should not have been reached when `max_rows` is None.

I've made a [pull request](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/pull/6863) to correct this.