# How to print pandas DataFrame entirely in jupyter notebooks?

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

I've been struggling with this very simple issue for a while now. I've looked for a similar question (which I find hard to believe that doesn't exist) but couldn't find it.

In jupyter notebookx, whenever you print a long DataFrame or Series, it supresses a few lines, indicating that there are hidden lines with `...`, I'd just like to know how to avoid that, and print all of it.

Example in the image attached

[image]

Comment: it's a pandas display option, the output is truncated by default, see the [docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/options.html#frequently-used-options) you need to change the `max_rows` attribute to see more rows

Comment: dupe: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22824104/python-pandas-increase-maximum-number-of-rows and related http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11707586/python-pandas-how-to-widen-output-display-to-see-more-columns/11711637#11711637

Comment: print(mydf.to_string()) you could do like this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on @EdChum 's answer:

It is not a jupyter notebook option, rather a `pandas` option.

In the [docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/options.html#frequently-used-options) you'll find that you can change the option using the command:

```
pd.set_option('max_rows', 7)
```

Comment: The proposed command does no longer work as it matches multiple options (`OptionError: 'Pattern matched multiple keys'`). This works:

`pd.set_option('display.max_rows', 7)`